# Put decimal separator after the first two digits in R

Tags: r, decimal-point

I have downloaded a table of temperature data from a datalogger where the decimal points dissapeared. Here is a fragment:

```
temperature<-c( 227725, 208957, 210834, 214588, 218342)
date<-c("2022-06-14 12:02:01 UTC", "2022-06-14 12:32:01 UTC", "2022-06-14 13:02:01 UTC", "2022-06-14 13:32:01 UTC", "2022-06-14 14:02:01 UTC")

df<-data.frame(date,temperature)


df
                     date temperature
1 2022-06-14 12:02:01 UTC      227725
2 2022-06-14 12:32:01 UTC      208957
3 2022-06-14 13:02:01 UTC      210834
4 2022-06-14 13:32:01 UTC      214588
5 2022-06-14 14:02:01 UTC      218342
```

I already know that the decimal point should be after the first two digits.

Is there a way to insert the decimal separator?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it an option to divide `temperature` by 10,000? (i.e. are they all 6 digits exactly?)

Comment: Yes, @PBulls, that can be an easy solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numbers may not be all six-digit but you are sure that the decimal point must come after the second digit, then the following should work:

1. convert to character `as.character(df$temperature`
2. use `gsub` to replace the first 2 digits with themselves plus a dot `gsub("^(\\d{2})", "\\1.", as.character(df$temperature))`
3. convert back to a number `as.numeric(gsub("^(\\d{2})", "\\1.", as.character(df$temperature)))`

So,

```
df$temperature <- as.numeric(gsub("^(\\d{2})", "\\1.", as.character(df$temperature)))

print(df)
                     date temperature
1 2022-06-14 12:02:01 UTC     22.7725
2 2022-06-14 12:32:01 UTC     20.8957
3 2022-06-14 13:02:01 UTC     21.0834
4 2022-06-14 13:32:01 UTC     21.4588
5 2022-06-14 14:02:01 UTC     21.8342
```

Answer (score 3):

Another base R solution:

```
transform(df, temperature = temperature * 10 ^(2 - nchar(temperature)))

                     date temperature
1 2022-06-14 12:02:01 UTC     22.7725
2 2022-06-14 12:32:01 UTC     20.8957
3 2022-06-14 13:02:01 UTC     21.0834
4 2022-06-14 13:32:01 UTC     21.4588
5 2022-06-14 14:02:01 UTC     21.8342
```